# Unity3D - Error building Player: Win32Exception:

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I am having a new error when I am building an android version of my game, This build fail has only been happening after my recent upgrade to Unity 4.5.5f1 from 4.3.something. I see many other people had similar issues to this before and I have already tried these solutions with no success.

- Copying/cutting zipalign.exe from build-tools to tools.
- Setting JAVA_HOME to C:Program Files(x86)Javajre7 and to C:Program -Files(x86)Javajre1.8.0_25bin (JAVA_HOME was not originally there I had to create this)
- Updating/reinstall both 32/64 bit Java
- Deleting and reinstalling my SDK
- Updating SDK to only API 21
- Updating SDK to only API 20
- copying Java.exe from Windows/SysWOW64 to Windows/System 32
- Uninstall all versions of Java and Java SE Dev Kit from control Panel, deleted all SDK and Eclipse from c: and completed a new install of 64 bit eclipse adt bundle and Java 32 and 64 bit.

So I am currently running Windows 7 (64 Bit) Service Pack 1 - Unity 4.5.5f1. ADT bundle for 64 bit with API 21, Java for both 64 bit and 32 bit (java 1.8 v 25), I deleted JAVA_HOME setting as it wasn't there previously and am still getting the following error:

```
Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:Program Files (x86)Javajre1.8.0_25binjavac.exe', CommandLine='-bootclasspath "C:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-21android.jar" -d "C:UsersShawnDocumentsSimonGameTempStagingAreabinclasses" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "comfacebookandroidManifest.java" "comfacebookandroidR.java" "comtwocogmimicManifest.java" "comtwocogmimicR.java"', CurrentDirectory='C:UsersShawnDocumentsSimonGameTempStagingAreagen'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

UPDATE / EDIT: I pushed JAVA_HOME to my JDK folder C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin and now am getting a new (but very similar) error.

> Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='javac.exe',
>   CommandLine='-bootclasspath
>   "C:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-21\android.jar"
>   -d "C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\SimonGame\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6
>   -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com\facebook\android\Manifest.java" "com\facebook\android\R.java" "com\twocog\mimic\Manifest.java"
>   "com\twocog\mimic\R.java"',
>   CurrentDirectory='C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\SimonGame\Temp\StagingArea\gen'

Comment: Make sure that javac.exe is really in your path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin). It tends to move mysteriously. If not, just find it somewhere inside C:\Program Files\Java and copy to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution and it was all too easy... Back to basics!
Javac.exe is a jdk file while java.exe is jre. After confirming the path was to jdk I restarted my computer and it works. Hopefully anyone having a similar issue can use the above steps and its useful to someone.